# Billing agreement description not showing full text in paypal sandbox checkout page

Tags: paypal

I have a paypal checkout page where in order summary i am displaying some text inside Billing agreement description. Text is displaying correctly but it's not showing full text length.
[image]

This is what i want to display.

$nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0=".urlencode("Your account will NOT be charged at this time. This verification is for security purposes only to prevent fraudulent use. Following your Free Trial period, you agree to pay a monthly fee of $fds/month per location for unlimited offer posting. Additional options that you select, i.e. paid offer positions, will be billed every 2-4 days. Thank you for joining fasdfdsa!");

Comment: "_fasdfdsa_" ... left hand random fingers on a Qwerty keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [SetExpressCheckout](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/) documentation, the L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION parameter only accepts 127 characters.

> Description of goods or services associated with the billing
>   agreement. This field is required for each recurring payment billing
>   agreement. PayPal recommends that the description contain a brief
>   summary of the billing agreement terms and conditions. For example,
>   buyer is billed at "9.99 per month for 2 years". **Character length and
>   limitations: 127 single-byte alphanumeric characters.**

That description is meant to be short and sweet.  Any details like this that you need to provide should be done on your site prior to sending the user to PayPal for payment.